# Can I define a variable that contains a URL (youtube) and call \includemedia with it?

Tags: macros, urls, external-files, strings, media9

I can successfully embed a video in my latex file using a syntax like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{book}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{media9}
    \begin{document}
        \includemedia[
        width=4in,height=3in,
        activate=pageopen,
        flashvars={
         modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
        &autohide=1       % controlbar autohide
        &showinfo=0       % no title and other info before start
        }
        ]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/Ssz7uq6wRFQ?rel=0}  
    \end{document}
```

However, I fail to do this with a variable:

```
documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{book}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\UrlLocation}{http://www.youtube.com/v/Ssz7uq6wRFQ?rel=0}

\includemedia[
  width=4in,height=3in,
  activate=pageopen,
  flashvars={
    modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
   &autohide=1       % controlbar autohide
   &showinfo=0       % no title and other info before start
  }
]{}{\UrlLocation} 
\end{document}
```

is there a way to define a string variable that contains the URL and call \includemedia with this variable?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Can you (or someone) report in which PDF reader and OS any of this works. For example: in Acrobat Reader 9.4.1 in Linux (Fedora 20) this hangs.

Answer (score 3):

An update (v. 0.37, 2013/11/27) of `media9` is on the way to CTAN which will cope with this.

Comment: @user41763 You can check the 'answered' mark.